# How do I add a column into a table?

Tags: mysql

as the title says, I'm having trouble about adding a column into a table, and I thought you could help me.

The column I'm trying to add is for a server, a gaming one I'd rather say, and for some reason INSERT INTO and ADD don't seem to work. INSERT INTO gives me an error message, but ADD doesn't even seem to exist as a command.

```sql
ALTER TABLE users
INSERT INTO users (Color)
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax
> to use near '' at line 2

Comment: What makes you think that this is the correct syntax? `INSERT` inserts new rows into a table, not new columns

Comment: Please search before you ask the question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INSERT` is a `DML(Data Manipulation Language)` command, you need to use `DDL(Data Definition Language)` command instead. Like below :

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD COLUMN Color varchar(50)
```

Comment: This still does not work. Again, ADD just doesn't seem to be a command in my DataBase. And the error I get is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD COLUMN users (Color)' at line 1

Comment: @Presiune please check again.

Comment: It does indeed work now, thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you have to add a new column into an existing table in `mysql`

```
ALTER TABLE tabel_name ADD COLUMN new_field_name <data_type>
```

So your modify query has to be like this:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN color varchar(10)
```

Comment: I have already solved the problem,  but thank you for helping.

Comment: As if this question has never ever been asked and answered here on SO before...